# boxplot catergories don't line up Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, boxplot

I am having a problem, with the categories of two box plots. From the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Taylby/wxpqsr9b/4/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'boxplot',
            inverted: true
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Medication Prescription between start date and stop date'
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: true
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ["Males","Females"],
            title: {
                text: 'Cohort'
            },
            max:1
        },

        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Interval between events'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 2413.8,
                color: 'gray',
                width: 1,
                height: 100,
                label: {
                    text: "Males Average",
                    align: 'center',
                    style: {
                        color: 'gray'
                    }
                }},
                {
                value: 16149.474524390858,
                color: 'gray',
                width: 1,
                height: 100,
                label: {
                    text: 'males +3SDs',
                    align: 'center',
                    style: {
                        color: 'gray'
                    }
                }},                
                {
                value: -11321.87452439086,
                color: 'gray',
                width: 1,
                height: 100,
                label: {
                    text: 'females -3SDs',
                    align: 'center',
                    style: {
                        color: 'gray'
                    }
                }},                
                {
                value: 1706.6,
                color: 'gray',
                width: 1,
                height: 100,
                label: {
                    text: 'C2 +3SDs',
                    align: 'center',
                    style: {
                        color: 'gray'
                    }
                }}              
            ],

        },

        series: [{            
     name: "Males",
        data: [
                [0,21,69,413,11566]
              ]             
        }, {           
       name: "Females",
        data:[
                [5,22,70,581,7860]
             ]          
        }]
    });
});
```

you can see that there are two groups, Males and Females - however the box plot doesn't line up with the label.

Much appreciated for any thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add x index (first param in your data point).

```
series: [{
        name: "Males",
        data: [
            [0, 0, 21, 69, 413, 11566]
        ]
    }, {
        name: "Females",
        data: [
            [1, 5, 22, 70, 581, 7860]
        ]
    }]
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wxpqsr9b/5/

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!